# Undefined field CloseDate in Report custom summary formula

Tags: reporting, formula

Hi I am very new to Salesforce. I'm trying to write a custom formula, stated below.

```
IF(FISCAL_YEAR:MAX=2015,
CASE(MONTH ( CloseDate ),
1,20000,
2,21000,
3,22000,
4,23000,
5,24000,
6,25000,
7,26000,
8,27000,
9,28000,
10,29000,
11,30000,
12,31000,0),
IF(FISCAL_YEAR:MAX=2014,
CASE(MONTH ( CloseDate ),
1, 32000,
2, 33000,
3,34000,
4,35000,
5,36000,
6,37000,
7,38000,
8,39000,
9,40000,
10,41000,
11,42000,
12,43000,0),0
)
)
```

I have checked the label name of `Close Date` field under `opportunity`, it shows `CloseDate`. but when I use the same in custom formula it shows error as

> Error: Invalid custom summary formula definition: Field CloseDate does
>   not exist. Check spelling.

Please help me on this.

Thanks.

Comment: I don't think [custom summery formula](https://help.salesforce.com/HTViewHelpDoc?id=reports_csf_tips.htm&language=en_US) can take Date or DateTime type field.

Answer (score 0):

For this type of case, you can create the Formula Field in Opportunity and Need to get the Month of CloseDate. And do with the following formula

```
IF(FISCAL_YEAR:MAX=2013,
CASE(Opportunity.Close_Month__c:MAX,
1,20000,
2,21000,
3,22000,
4,23000,
5,24000,
6,25000,
7,26000,
8,27000,
9,28000,
10,29000,
11,30000,
12,31000,0),
IF(FISCAL_YEAR:MAX=2014,
CASE(Opportunity.Close_Month__c:MAX,
1,32000,
2,33000,
3,34000,
4,35000,
5,36000,
6,37000,
7,38000,
8,39000,
9,40000,
10,41000,
11,42000,
12,43000,0),0
)
)
```

Refer the below link...

http://opfocus.com/use-salesforce-custom-summary-formulas-tto-track-target-vs-actual/

Hope this might helps...